# How to read paths from txt and input the files in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, file, text, input, path

I have one txt file whitch contains paths to a lot of other txt files of data in my project , i am quite new to matlab , so i cant figure out a way how to add the first txt file with the paths and make matlab read all the paths and add all the other txt files ?

Any help is apriciated , thanks for your time :)

Comment: I would look into the `textscan` function. You can first use this to recover all the paths in your initial text file, and then use it to read in any data from the subsequent text files.

Comment: pls share a part of code which you have tried and not giving the req result, that would be easy for reader to answer you precisely